# Phantomjs doesn't get the args from php exec

Tags: php, exec, phantomjs, param

I'm trying to run a simple phantomjs program passing some args from php and the only arg that my js can read is the first one (args[0]).

Here is the code.

PHP:

```
...
$resp = exec("phantomjs phantom/test.js hello other args");
...
```

phantom/test.js:

```
var args = require('system').args;

str = 'Args: ';
args.forEach(function (arg, i) {
    str += (i + ': ' + arg);
});

str += ' Length: '+args.length;
str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

console.log(str);

phantom.exit();
```

The output is:

```
Args: 0: phantom/test.js Length: 1
```

I'm using Windows 7. I tried to run this code direcly from the windows command line (cmd-> 'phantomjs test.js some args') and it worked properly, so, I think that the problem lies on php and its relation with the "require('system')" of phantomjs.

Srry for my horrible english.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is appending string into a single variable.

Try the code below

```
$resp = exec("phantomjs phantom/test.js arg1 arg2 ..... argN");
```

Now the phantomjs code would be like this to catch the arguments sent from Php file

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

var argument1 = args[1];
var argument2 = args[2];
.
.
.
var argument3 = args[N];
```

You can use values stored the variables.